# Rendering a region in solid viewport shading?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to render a region where it is rendered by cycles, but everything outside the render region is in solid viewport shading?

Use case is if I have multiple objects lined up one by one and I want to work on their materials. I would like to be able to see the objects in the viewport, but render region doesn't allow that in rendered viewport shading.

I am not asking how to render a region (CTRL+B). I already know how to do that.*

Comment: Do you want to have, in the 3D viewport, the rendered view of a selected object? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth That's what CTRL+B does. What happens currently is that everything outside the rendered region is not rendered at all. I want the outside region to be render in solid view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug, or missing feature, from what I could gather from this bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T63064

Comment: Thanks for letting us know :). Don't forget to mark the question as accepted **✓** so others can easily find it.